# Control the mail sending method to verify some mail before sending remainder

Tags: vba, outlook

I have to send a few hundred mails. The VBA code is working.

Outlook VBA has a `.Send` method, which sends the mail without pausing. It also has a `.display` method, which displays a mail item. The displayed mail can then be sent by clicking on the Send button in Outlook.

The requirement is:
In a loop of say, 100 mails, the user should be able to review the first few messages. They should be displayed and then sent by clicking the Send button.
Once the user is ok with a few sample mails, he should be able to send the rest of the messages without reviewing them.

In short, till the user is comfortable the `mailitem.display` should work and thereafter `mailitem.send` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, when you loop (from 1 to 100), call `MailItem.Display(true)` for `i <= 10` and `MailItem.Send` otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it will work . Will check and confirm. 

However, want to know whether the decision to continue with sending can be made dynamically. As an example, the user checks the first n mails in Display(true) mode and then decides to continue in Send mode for the remaining Total Count - n mails.

Comment: You can prompt the user wit ha message box after 10 iterations whether they want 10 more or not.